# Why does my dash app break when I add a second drop down?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am making a dash app to visualise Transport for London travel data - I have two dropdown (one to select mode of transport and one to select the journey start station). When I added this second dropdown, all of a sudden my app does not want to show any data. Is there something inherently wrong with my code that I can not see? Any help is appreciated

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/darkly/bootstrap.min.css'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import and clean dataset
# df = pd.read_csv('Nov09JnyExport.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('data_with_long_lat.csv')
df.columns = [col.lower() for col in df.columns]



df.rename(columns = {'downo' : 'day num'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'daytype' : 'day'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'downo' : 'day of week'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'jnytyp' : 'jny type'}, inplace=True)

print(df.columns)


dropdown_style = {
            'width': '50%',  
            'font-size': '16px', 
            'color': '#141718', 
            'border-radius': '4px',
            'border': '2px solid #343a40', 
            'background-color': '#b8c2cd', 
            'padding': '10px',
            'box-shadow': '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prepare list of stations for one of the dropdowns

# Get unique station names
xstations = df['startstn'].unique()

# Create a dictionary to map station names to their string representations
station_dict = {str(station): station for station in xstations}

# Create a list of dictionaries for dropdown options
station_dropdown = [{'label': key.strip().title(), 'value': value} for key, value in station_dict.items()]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([

html.H1("Transport for London - One Week in 2009", style= {'text-align':'center'}),

dcc.Dropdown(id = 'select_mode',
             options = [
                 {"label": 'Bus', "value" : "LTB"},
                 {"label": 'Underground', "value" : "LUL"},
                 {"label": 'National Rail', "value" : "NR"},
                 {"label": 'Docklands Light Railway', "value" : "DLR"},
                 {"label": 'Overground', "value" : "LRC"},
                 {"label": 'Tram', "value" : "TRAM"}],
                multi=True,
                value = 'LUL', # London Underground will be the initial/defualt value
                style= dropdown_style
                ),
dcc.Dropdown(id = 'select_station',
             options = station_dropdown,
             searchable = True,
             placeholder = 'Search for a station',
             style= dropdown_style,
             value = None
),
html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
html.Br(), # break line

dcc.Graph(id = 'jny_by_day', figure={})

])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect graphs with Dash components
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id = 'output_container', component_property = 'children'), # Output will be children in html.Div.
     Output(component_id = 'jny_by_day', component_property = 'figure')], # Don't use square brackets if only one Output
     [Input(component_id = 'select_mode', component_property = 'value'),
      Input(component_id = 'select_station', component_property = 'value')]
)

def update_graph(mode_slctd, station_slctd): # each argument connects to an input (above). One input = one argument, two inputs = two arguments etc. The argument always refers to the component property
    print(mode_slctd)
    print(type(mode_slctd))

    container = f"The mode of transport chosen by the user was: {mode_slctd}"

    dff = df.copy()
    dff = dff[(dff['subsystem'] == mode_slctd) & (dff['startstn'] == station_slctd)]


    # Build bar chart
    order_of_days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    jny_by_day = dff['day'].value_counts()
    jny_by_day_df = jny_by_day.reset_index()
    jny_by_day_df.columns = ['Day', 'Journeys']
    bar_chart = px.bar(jny_by_day_df, x = 'Day', y = 'Journeys',
                       title = 'Number of Journeys Each Day',
                       labels = {'Day' : 'Day', 'Journeys' : 'Journeys'},
                       template = 'plotly_dark',
                       category_orders= {'Day' : order_of_days})
  

    return container, bar_chart # what is returned here goes into the output. If you have two outputs you have to return two things here. The order of the return matters

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Tried to make the station drop down just two values that I know are present in the start stn column - same thing

tried removing the second input - same thing

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but why do you have `,` after each `dcc.Dropdown()` call?

Comment: @Barmar this is my first dash app, I assumed you separate each dropdown by a comma, thanks for raising that though I'll go ahead and remove :)

Comment: But you're not separating anything when you put comma at the end of an expression. It just turns it into a 1-element tuple. You can get unexpected results if the statement is an assignment, e.g. compare `foo = 1` with `foo = 1,` when you do `print(foo)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are setting `multi = True` so that in your callback you should use `isin` instead of `==`.
So I think you should change from  `dff = dff[(dff['subsystem'] == mode_slctd) & (dff['startstn'] == station_slctd)]` to  `dff = dff[(dff['subsystem'].isin(mode_slctd)) & (dff['startstn'].isin(station_slctd)]`